# How can I get the correct json in FlatBuffers?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I successfully parsed the data，but then are not correct json data.How can I get the correct json in FlatBuffers?
My code:

```
auto result = GenerateText(parser, in, &json_data);
flatbuffers::SaveFile("test.json",json_data.c_str(), json_data.size(), true);
```

test.json`s content:

```
{
  account: "0520-1",
  passwd: "",
  device: "test",
  token: "11aasasdfasdf"
}
```

It cannot be parsed correctly by JSON.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `strict_json` option on the `Parser`, otherwise you don't get the quoted field names that JSON requires:

```
auto options = IDLOptions();
options.strict_json = true;
auto parser = Parser(options);
```